# Bit banging an MCP3008 with pigpio bb_spi returns all 1023s

Tags: gpio, pigpio

I started to try to read an MCP3008 ADC using SPI bit banging with pigpio. I wrote the unattractive little script below, starting from the example in the [pigpio documentation](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_spi_open) and here is a screenshot of my output.

I believe that this should read the lowest four channels of the ADC and print the output. Channels 0 to 3 are connected to +5V, GND, +5V, floating, so I expected to see values like 1023, 0, 1023, xxx where the last would be noise.

Instead I see all 1023's.

Have I done something terribly wrong?

[image]

```
import pigpio
import time

CE1  = 2
MISO = 3
MOSI = 4
SCLK = 17

pi = pigpio.pi()

pi.bb_spi_open(CE1, MISO, MOSI, SCLK, 10000, 3)

nums = [128 + n for n in (16, 32, 48, 64)]
while True:
    print "wow!"
    for num in nums:
        print "num! ", num
        count, data = pi.bb_spi_xfer(CE1, [1, num, 0])

        print "count = ", count, data = [byte for byte in data]

        value = ((data[1]&3)<<8) | data[2]
        print "value = ", value
        time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Try sending **[1, 128+num, 0]**.  You might be in differential mode.

Comment: @joan thanks, I'll give it a try in a bit (not near my pi at the moment). `num` already has a 128 in it already; `nums = [128 + n for n in (16, 32, 48, 64)]` so would the 2nd 128 wrap it back to zero, or cause a problem because it would then be greater than 256? I don't understand what "mode" actually means. I see that it is mentioned in the pigpio documentation. Maybe I should ask a separate question on that?

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice nums, I read what I assumed to be there.  For channels 0 to 3 you should use **nums = [128 + n for n in (0, 1, 2, 3)]**.  Personally I'd just use **for num in range(4):** and **[1, 128+num, 0]** as I think it looks clearer.

Comment: @joan ok thanks! I did call it an "unattractive script" :-)

Comment: @joan I'd thought that the 128 was to set the MSB in the 2nd word (now with a red box around it in the image) to 1 to indicate single-sided (as opposed to differential) operation. The reason I chose `16, 32, 48, 64` was that the three bit address for ADC channel D0, D1, D2 seem to be bits 4, 5 and 6 in that byte. Shouldn't `num` in `pi.bb_spi_xfer(CE1, [1, num, 0])` be this byte with the four lowest bits set to zero?

Comment: My bad again.  I have just looked at my Python code and I use **[1, (8+channel)<<4, 0]**.  Where channel is 0 to 3 for the channels you use.

Comment: I also use **value = ((data[1] << 8) | data[2]) & 0x3FF** to calculate the returned value.

Comment: @joan I've just asked [Two timing frames for SPI reads of MCP3008 ADC, any advantages or disadvantages of either one?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/92307/35753)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments by @Joan (above) were extremely helpful! MCP3008 does indeed use `mode=0`, where I had it erroneously set to `3`.

The following works very nicely!

```
import pigpio
import time

CS   = 2
MISO = 3
MOSI = 4
SCLK = 17
MODE = 0

pi = pigpio.pi()

pi.bb_spi_close(CS)  # because I use ctrl-C to break each time

pi.bb_spi_open(CS, MISO, MOSI, SCLK, 10000, MODE)

while True:
    for n in range(4):

        ct, data = pi.bb_spi_xfer(CS, [1, (8+n)<<4, 0])

        val  = ((data[1]<<8) | data[2]) & 0x3FF

        print (n, ct, val, "data=", [byte for byte in data] )

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @joan works like a charm, yippee!